# List QR code apps installed

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I want to build an app that needs to scans qr codes. For this purpose, I have integrated the zxing sources in my project and it works fine 95% of the time.

The other 5% (does not work for some unknown reason) I would like to check if the user has a scanner app present and if so consume it through an Intent.

The question is:

- How can I list all scanner apps (similar to when a users clicks share and several apps are shown i.e. Gmail, Youtube, SMS, etc.) ?
- If first question is not possible, I could just look in the store for the most popular apps and check one by one if this app is installed. What fallback does this approach have? do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");

        String title = (String) getResources().getText(R.string.chooser_title);

        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);

        startActivityForResult(chooser, CUSTOM_REQUEST_QR_SCANNER);
```

Comment: this does not answer the question at all.

Comment: THe above code will look for any app that is registered to handle zxing broadcast intents.  You cant just look for any qr code reading app unless they share a common broadcast intent